# How to animate a search bar using only css and keeping input open for user input?

Tags: html, css

I attempted to make a search bar template that I can use in various places in my website. It should work by hovering over the icon, making the icon from circle to square, and when a user clicks on the icon it expands the search input. I am having trouble with getting the input field to remain expanded, when I click on the input it closes. I do not want to use JS or jQuery on this. Also when you click on the button again or any other part of the web page the input should close and the information typed should be emptied.

Here is the css section of the code:

```css
 .search_bar {
     position: relative;
     top: 0;
     float: right;
     right: 20px;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: red;
    }
    
    .search_input {
     width: 0%;
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     float: right;
     height: 36px;
     border: 2px solid var(--accent_colour_1);
     outline: none;
     transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .search_icon {
     float: right;
     outline: none;
     padding: 0px;
     margin: 0px;
     text-align: center; 
     height: 40px;
     width: 40px;
     right: 0px;
     border-radius: 100%;
     background-color: var(--dark_colour);
     transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .search_icon:hover {
     border-radius: 0;
     transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .search_icon:focus {
     border-radius: 0px;
    }
    
    .search_icon:focus + .search_input {
     width: 50%;
     transition: 0.3s;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="search_bar">
        <button class="search_icon">S</button> 
        <input type="text" name="#" class="search_input">
           
       </div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: From your requirement it is very difficult and almost impossible to get thing don without javascript :( we can track the state when you lick the button the input shrink when you click the button the input stretch out, if you want js solution tell me

Comment: @CuongHoang I get what you are saying, I guess a JS option is better than nothing! Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, it should work:

```
.search_input:focus {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the `width` of `input` is set to `0%` and it only expands up to `50%` when the `button` is focused.

To keep the input field at the same width when click, you can set the `width` value for the `input:focus`.

```css
 .search_bar {
     position: relative;
     top: 0;
     float: right;
     right: 20px;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: red;
    }
    
    .search_input {
     width: 0%;
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     float: right;
     height: 36px;
     border: 2px solid var(--accent_colour_1);
     outline: none;
     transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .search_icon {
     float: right;
     outline: none;
     padding: 0px;
     margin: 0px;
     text-align: center; 
     height: 40px;
     width: 40px;
     right: 0px;
     border-radius: 100%;
     background-color: var(--dark_colour);
     transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .search_icon:hover {
     border-radius: 0;
     transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .search_icon:focus {
     border-radius: 0px;
    }
    
    .search_icon:focus + .search_input,
    .search_input:focus /* added this */ {
     width: 50%;
     transition: 0.3s;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="search_bar">
        <button class="search_icon">S</button> 
        <input type="text" name="#" class="search_input">
           
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery instead of CSS. when click outside the focus that was on the button is removed. check below link. thanks

https://codepen.io/Xenio/pen/oJyGLP`jquery`

Comment: he only asked for CSS only.

Answer (score 0):

**Not Exactly Work. It closed and open again**

```css
 .search_bar {
     position: relative;
     top: 0;
     float: right;
     right: 20px;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: red;
    }
    
    .search_input {
     width: 0%;
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     float: right;
     height: 36px;
     border: 2px solid var(--accent_colour_1);
     outline: none;
     transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .search_icon {
     float: right;
     outline: none;
     padding: 0px;
     margin: 0px;
     text-align: center; 
     height: 40px;
     width: 40px;
     right: 0px;
     border-radius: 100%;
     background-color: var(--dark_colour);
     transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .search_icon:hover {
     border-radius: 0;
     transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .search_icon:focus {
     border-radius: 0px;
    }
    
    .search_icon:focus + .search_input {
     width: 50%;
     transition: 0.3s;
    }

    .search_inputtext {
     width: 50%;
     transition: 0.3s;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="search_bar">
        <button class="search_icon">S</button> 
        <input type="text" name="#" onClick="this.classList.toggle('search_inputtext');" class="search_input">
           
       </div>
```